# I'm [submitting] a burnination request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Today's dodgy tag is [submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/submitting), 42 questions and no followers, so it's under the 50 questions for a formal review, but I'd like an informal check at least before I do anything.

> 1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It maybe describes the contents, but it's very ambiguous; most of the questions are about submitting apps for review, but [app-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-store) or [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook), etc would be more specific.

There's other questions where [submit-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/submit-button) or [form-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/form-submit) (or just no tag at all) would be better.

> 2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

I think not; the first two tags mentioned say customer support-type issues are off-topic, and the second two tags cover the remaining cases.

> 3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No; renaming to more specific tags does, though.

> 4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, as pointed out above, the submit button and app store submission are two completely different things.

I can probably remove the tag from most of the questions, so the Roomba should auto-delete the tag soon, thus Trogdor may not be needed.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of these are using this over [submit]. I say we cleanup and then synonym

Comment: I think it is fine to burninate this with the informal burnination procedure.

Comment: Don't just retag. Burnination is more about closing, deleting the off-topic posts, and retagging only where necessary. Try to vote to close the off-topic posts, and not just remove the tags.